# How do I find when a Custom Label was created or modified from API

Tags: soql, soap-api, metadata-api, tooling-api

How do I find when a Custom Label was created, modified, or who Created or Modified it from an API ?

I have checked Partner WSDL, Metadata API and Tooling API but none of them give out this information. Metadata API provides information about Custom Labels but does not give out the System Fields :

> ### [From Metadata API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/manifest_samples.htm#manifest_standard_objects)
>
> Other standard fields aren't supported, including system fields (such as CreatedById or
>   LastModifiedDate) and autonumber fields.

I have found this Idea (and voted): [Expose Last Modified information (date and user) through the Metadata API](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000kw5GAAQ&sort=2) but it'd be nice if there's something out there already.

Answer (score 1):

No way that I know of, but the painful way I do it is by creating a view from the custom labels part of setup that includes the alias of the createdby and the lastmodifiedby and then copying that into excel.  Since those are hyperlinks, you can then write a function in excel to extract the hyperlink values which include the 005 userid.  It's ugly but it works after lots and lots of copy-pasting.